# How can I change the way my navbar aligns at different breakpoints in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap [Cover](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/) template as a basis for a very simple business / CV site I'm making and learning along the way. I understand the concept of breakpoints. I've noticed three different styles of the navbar (and page) as I reduce the browser width:

1. "Cover" and navbar are left and right aligned but in an invisible fixed-width box
2. Same as above but that invisible box is now the same width as the browser window (i.e. there isn't any margin like above), the elements have jumped outwards
3. "Cover" stacks on top of the navbar items.

If I twitch the window width between stage 1 and 2 I can see the elements jumping around. This is what I'd like to change, so that stage 1 continues to compress the items closer and closer and then when they are close to touching, it moves to stage 3 (i.e. get rid of stage 2)

Is this possible?

Comment: impossible or possible, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using CSS media queries.

If you inspect the `<div class="masthead clearfix">` element, you will see that as the browser window changes size, different styles are applied.

Stage 1. Browser window width > 992px, the width of this element is 700px
Stage 2. Broswer window width > 768px, the width of this element is 100% and spans the whole page.
Stage 3. Browser window width <= 768px, the width of this element is still 100%.

You will also see that the `<h3 class="masthead-brand">` and `<ul class="nav masthead-nav">` have styles that float them left and right until the browser window width is less than 768px.

If you don't want to see a change between stage 1 and 2, you will want to either remove either of the rules I have mentioned in stage 1 or 2 or override them with your own styles as well as overriding the styles that float the `h3` and `ul` left and right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! You explained it clearly and easily to me. I'm going to dig into the code and have a play around.